PyPy не находит модуль sympy
Через командную строку запускаю скрипт с помощью PyPy. Выдаёт ошибку
F:\Other\pypy3.10-v7.3.16-win64>pypy palindroms_factor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Other\pypy3.10-v7.3.16-win64\palindroms_factor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sympy import factorint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'

Как исправить? Как заставить его увидеть sympy?
Что в самом скрипте:
from sympy import factorint
import time
ak1 = time.perf_counter()
def sum_of_div(n):
    factors = factorint(n)
    result = 1
    for prime, exponent in factors.items():
        result *= (prime**(exponent + 1) - 1) // (prime - 1)
    return result
for i in range (1, 1_000_000):
    result = sum_of_div(i)
    if result == int(str(result)[::-1]) and i == int(str(i)[::-1]): print(f'({i}, {result})')   
ak2 = time.perf_counter()
print(ak2-ak1)


pypy -m ensurepip

pypy -m pip install sympy

Проблема решена

Скорее всего, вам просто нужно установить пакет
pypy -m pip install sympy


Да, спасибо! Всё именно так

@KIRILLONF.M., если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый (галка напротив ответа).
